# Trailing slash and dash remove bug with htaccess and apache server

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)-certifications/([^/]+)-exams$ certpage.php?cname=$1 [L]
```

i want URL like "mysite.com/hp-certifications/emc-exam" but the above code is not working 
can any body help?

Comment: What do you mean by not working ?

Comment: when i use above url its goes to 404

Comment: does not redirect to "certpage.php"

Comment: i just changed the position of the above code and it worked

Comment: @rizcmt195: You should add the solution as an answer (explaining after/before what the `RewriteRule` has to appear), and accept it.